# Calculte checksum of file located in an cpio archive

Tags: linux, awk, sh, cpio

I have a kernel file located inside a cpio archive and I would like to calculate it's sha256sum. 
For that I redirected the archive output to the standard output and piped through `sha256sum`. 
I get the sum by using `awk`.

`KERNEL_CHECKSUM=$(cpio --to-stdout -i kernel.fat16 < archive.cpio  | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')`

This command works when it runs on a terminal. When run as a script, the checksum is not correctly calculated.

I suspect something related with the standard output but was unable to find the issue.

Comment: what shell are you using? If its `sh`, is it a symlink to something? How do you call the shell-script? Has the script a proper shebang? Please show the script.

Comment: Hi Fredrik, 
The shell is shIt's an `sh`, linked from `sh -> /bin/busybox.nosuid`
and  the script is called by the system() command.
I figured out that the wrong sha256sum is always the same, it's actually the hash of an empty array of bytes : `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

Comment: Do you set absolute path for `archive.cpio`? You can log `stderr` of `cpio` to check what wrong.